UML: How to model a SW activity that has two separate phases
I want to correctly model my RT/Embedded SW activity as a UML activity diagram.
My activity comprises two phases, where Phase 2 runs some (relatively “long”) time after Phase 1 has completed. (And, btw, so they are not parallel.)
Goal of question -- To know if:

My activity is one activity, or in fact two separate activities?

If indeed two separate activities, can I nevertheless legally model it on a single UML activity diagram (maybe optionally as two partitions)?


Additional detail:
The activities generate results in two phases. Let’s name them:
GenResultsPhaseONE and GenResultsPhaseTWO_andOutput
These two activities are not necessarily procedurally linked – but there is indeed a repeated synchronous processing Period, where, let’s say:

At Time T1, GenResults_Phase1 is invoked and generates & saves ResultData_Temp.

At Time T2, GenResults_Phase2_andOutput is invoked and reads
ResultData_Temp and processes it further, and generates updated
results, and outputs them.


Edit: Added one of the comments to the question to raise the idea and then negate it:
Phase 1 does not control or invoke Phase 2 or in any way pass a 'control token' to some 'master top-level' to cause Phase 2 to later run.
For sure, if Phase 1 would cease to exist there would be no reason for Phase 2 to run (and so maybe there is indeed a sanity check done by Phase 2, or just before it, to check that Phase 1 had run).
But I do not feel this can be considered that Phase 1 controls Phase 1.
They really are independent.

Since the end of the first phase controls the possible start of the second phase, there should be a control flow in between them. That means I would use an activity to model this. The two phases could be modeled by separate activities that could be called by CallBehaviorActions in the main activity. The result of the first phase would be given via an object flow to the action of the second phase.
It is not allowed to have multiple Activities in one Activity diagram.


Since the end of the first phase controls the possible start of the second phase,

I do not think one could say Phase 1 controls Phase 2. Phase 1 does not invoke Phase 2 or in any way pass a 'control token' to some 'master top-level' to cause Phase 2 to later run.
For sure, if Phase 1 would cease to exist there would be no reason for Phase 2 to run, and so maybe there is indeed a sanity check done by Phase 2, or just before it, to check that Phase 1 had run (in the processing loop instance).
So, do you still think there there should be a control flow in between them?

But I understand that the main thing is that you see them as two separate activities, and thus cannot be on the same activity diagram.

It is not the activity of phase 1 that controls phase 2. It is the main activity, that waits for activity 1 to finish. This creates a control token. The main activity  can then invoke the second phase by routing the token to the call behavior action. You can use call behavior actions, but you can also show everything that goes on in one activity.

I will have to check with my UML platform if I can define a 'super diagram' and pull in the two different activity diagrams Phase 1 and Phase 2 so that they will be side-by-side.

There is no “super diagram”. An activity has actions that can call other activities.

Why is nobody thinking of timers or signal receptions?

@JimL. Well, they could be used, but the problem as stated doesn't require them.

@AxelScheithauer: “These two activities are not necessarily procedurally linked – but there is indeed a repeated synchronous processing Period”

@JimL. Yes, that could be done with with time events. However, what exactly means "synchroneous processing period"? Two actions being synchronized? Who is synchronizing them? The key statement for me is, that the second action requires the result of the first. So, the straightforward thing to do is, to have a control flow in between them. Of course, other possibilities exist. Maybe the op needs to be more specific about the problem description.

@AxelScheithauer: indeed, the OP was unclear.
